# Django | How to pass a query string from response

Tags: django

How do I pass a query string from a response, meantime the relative template should also get loaded.

ex:

```
http://www.domain.com/test/?id=23423424
```

and `id=23423424` is a key that is saved in the DB, so need to attach this when processing the response.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do. Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, there are two ways to do this.  You can either do it in `urls.py` (and `views.py`, but that comes later) or in `views.py`.

**In views.py:**

```
def your_view(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)
    ## The rest of your view.
```

**In urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^test/\?id=(?P<id>\d+)$', 'path.to.your_view', {}, "your_view_name"),
)
```

**View for urls.py method:**

```
def your_view(request, id):
    ## The rest of your view.
```

Answer (score 2):

use request.GET.get('id') to get the ID form the query string.